# How to add images dynamically to Photoswipe? - Overview hidden

Tags: jquery, mobile, photoswipe

i am trying to attach images to Photoswipe dynamically.

```
$('#imgholder').on('tap', function(event){  
  (function(window,PhotoSwipe){                                                                         var                                                                                        options = {
preventHide: true,
getImageSource: function(obj){
return obj.url;
},
getImageCaption: function(obj){
return obj.caption;
}
},
function(){
for (var i = 0; i < images.length-1; i++)
{
instance = PhotoSwipe.attach([{url:images[i]}],options);
}
}
instance.show(0);
}(window,window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
});
```

I' am trying to avoid the Gallery Tag because i dont want to show the gallery overview. My urls are stored in a simple array.

```
var images = result.news[index].bilder_url.split("-,-");
```

Is it possible to attach this array to photoswipe or run a simple for loop? 
Or is there a different approach?

Thx in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function(window, PhotoSwipe){
var 
   options = {},
   instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( window.document.querySelectorAll('#Gallery a'), options);
   instance.show(1);   
}(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
```

Thats doing the trick :)

Found in the examples provided by PhotoSwipe.

Comment: can u please explain little more, where is json call or link request to server for data.???/